# unable to read functions from the bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have two files as below

**genericfunctions.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Install .net core
#
function InstallDotNetCore
{
  echo "installeddotnetcore"
}
#
function InstallMdsHooks
{
 echo "installedmdshooks"
}
#
function InstallNodeAgent
{
echo "installnodeagent"
}
```

**main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "BootStrap Started"

source /tmp/genericfunctions.sh

sudo apt-get update

InstallDotNetCore
InstallMdsHooks


echo "Bootstrap complete"
```

**error:**

```
xxxxxxx@xxxxxxtest2vm:/tmp$ sh main.sh
:All Args:
main.sh: 5: main.sh: source: not found
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-zesty-prod zesty InRelease
Hit:2 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/azurecore trusty InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful InRelease
Get:6 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [78.6 kB]
Hit:7 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease
Fetched 78.6 kB in 0s (111 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
main.sh: 9: main.sh: InstallDotNetCore: not found
main.sh: 10: main.sh: InstallMdsHooks: not found
```

:Bootstrap complete:

None of the functions from file1 are being called from file2. I have tried simply giving ./tmp/file1.sh. it was triggering all the functions in the file1. I want to trigger only specific functions.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use a full path rather than relative path.  Running `file1.sh` shouldn't have executed any of the functions, only loaded them.  What do you mean by triggering?

Comment: if you see the file 2 , it has functions from file 1 like InstallDotNetCore . my script stops executing after sudo apt-get update. the path I have given is the full path (./tmp/file1.sh)

error:
main.sh: line 9: InstallDocker: command not found
main.sh: line 10: InstallNodeAgent: command not found

Comment: Also the path you have given is **not** a full path.  The full path would not start with a `.`

Comment: Thank you Jesse:-) . is there a way we can call only specific functions in the file. /tmp/file1.sh is the absolute path I have given. I have tried below  scenarios 

source ./tmp/file1.sh : Unable to find the functions 
. /tmp/file1.sh: runs all the functions in the file1

Comment: Where are you getting this `main.sh: line 9: InstallDocker: command not found main.sh: line 10: InstallNodeAgent: command not found`?  I don't see main.sh.

Comment: Hi Jesse ,both files are in /tmp folder . In the file2.sh , I have to load the file1.sh and call specific functions . As per your comment above , I have tried giving source /tmp/file1.sh and ran it again. and here is the result 

Reading package lists... Done
main.sh: 9: main.sh: InstallDotNetCore: not found
main.sh: 10: main.sh: InstallMdsHooks: not found

Comment: main.sh is file2 , I apologize for not updating it here

Comment: @Bobby, can you please [edit] your question to show the actual scripts you have? So that there's no confusion between the script names (`main.sh` vs `file2.sh`). Then run them like you're planning to do and _copy and paste_ the command used to run them with, along with the errors, if any. You may probably want to make some mock-up functions for show, instead of what it is you're actually doing. But make sure the functions do something that's visible

Comment: Bobby, please stop commenting. Update your question instead.

Comment: @Bobby, since, right now, if you run those scripts, there's no way to tell if `InstallDotNetCore` gets called, since it doesn't do anything. And we can't really see the situation on your system, so any inaccuracies just get amplified.

Comment: If the files are in `/tmp` at least one of your problems is the period in `./tmp/`  That period is nonsense and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks jesse , I have removed the period(.) and updated it as below 
 source /tmp/genericfunctions.sh and ran the main.sh file again and it is the same error 
main.sh: 9: main.sh: InstallDotNetCore: not found
main.sh: 10: main.sh: InstallMdsHooks: not found

Comment: Thanks you all , I have ran the main.sh file as Bash mail.sh and it worked .

Answer (score 4):

Since both script files are `bash` scripts, you should run them using the `bash` shell interpreter, not the `sh` shell interpreter.

You have the correct `#!`-line in the script, so running it directly from the command line (`./main.sh`) should do the right thing, as long as the script is executable.

---

In `sh` scripts, functions are defined using

```
somefuctionname () {
    somefunctionbody
}
```

rather than with the keyword `function`. If you also use `.` (dot) in place of `source`, the script *would* have been able to run under `sh`, unless it used other special `bash` features.

Comment: @Bobby Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).